# Any straightforward proof of "in an abelian category, a pullback yields a monomorphism at cokernel level"?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Here is the question I encountered:

> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> s @>{f^\prime}>> a @>{\varphi^\prime}>> \bar a\\
> @V{g^\prime}VV @V{g}VV @V{\bar g}VV\\
> b @>{f}>> c @>{\varphi}>> \bar c
> \end{CD}$$
>
> Given a commutative diagram as above in an abelian category such that $(f^\prime,g^\prime)$ is a pullback of $(f,g)$ and  that $\varphi$, $\varphi^\prime$ are cokernel of $f$, $f^\prime$ respectively. Then  $\bar g$ is monic.

I proved it using diagram chasing but I wonder if there is any simpler and more straightforward proof. I view this as a small generalization of the fact that a pullback of an epimorphism is epic in an abelian category, I think it's highly possible to find one, but I haven't succeeded yet. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Hi, can you post your diagram chasing? Because I can't get the proof. Thank you!

Comment: @freedfromthereal Never mind, the diagram chasing method is not so illustrative. My newest thought is that I can prove the case when $f$ is epic or monic at first, and then combine these two special cases to yield the general one.

Comment: And what if $f$ is monic? This can be interesting for me.

Comment: @freedfromthereal When $f$ is monic, it is the kernel of $\varphi$, and in this situation one can prove that $f'$ is the kernel of of $\varphi g$. In fact the monic case holds more generally than epic case, for in any category, the pullback of equalizer is again an equalizer.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the fact that pullbacks preserves kernels,

then we can deduce from this fact that the map on cokernels is a monomorphism

by using a spectral sequence argument.

---

First, we may regard the following pullback square as a double complex :

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
b @>{f^\prime}>> c\\
@A{g^\prime}AA @AA{g}A\\
s @>{f}>> a
\end{CD}$$

Computing rightwards, then the first two pages are given by

$$\newcommand{\on}{\operatorname}
_{>}E^1_{\bullet\bullet}:\quad\begin{CD}\on{Cok}(g')@>>>\on{Cok}(g)\\\\\on{Ker}(g')@>>>\on{Ker}(g)\end{CD}\quad\quad\quad{_{>}E^2_{\bullet\bullet}}:\quad\begin{CD}?&&&&?\\\\0&&&&0\end{CD}$$

(the arrows in $_>E^2_{\bullet\bullet}$ are omitted)

From this, we see that $_>E^{\infty}_{\bullet\bullet}={_>E^{2}_{\bullet\bullet}}$, and that there are two $0$'s at the bottom of $_>E^{\infty}_{\bullet\bullet}$.

Similary, if we compute upwards, the first two pages ought to be :

$$_{\wedge}E^1_{\bullet\bullet}:\quad\begin{CD}\on{Ker}(f') &&&& \on{Cok}(f)\\@AAA && @AAA\\\on{Ker}(f')&&&& \on{Cok}(f)\end{CD}\quad\quad\quad{_{\wedge}E^2_{\bullet\bullet}}:\quad\begin{CD}0&&&&?\\\\0&&&&\star\end{CD}$$

and similarly that $_{\wedge}E^{\infty}_{\bullet\bullet}={_{\wedge}E^{2}_{\bullet\bullet}}$.

If we can show that $\star=0$, then we are done.

Since the original double complex has finitely many nonzero terms, we are done by noticing

$$_{>}E^{2}_{\bullet\bullet}={_{>}E^{\infty}_{\bullet\bullet}}={_{\wedge}E^{\infty}_{\bullet\bullet}}={_{\wedge}E^{2}_{\bullet\bullet}}$$

---

Other examples on proving some diagrammatic results in abelian categories by spectral sequences

can be found in [This note on Spectral Sequence by Vakil](https://tinyurl.com/rbl55mj).